# Opening url (blog) with scroll view

Tags: cocoa, scrollview

I've tried so many links and they all revert back to a web view.

I only just got Xcode and I'm pretty new to all this stuff, its complete different to C and Java.

Anyways, I have added a scroll view to my frame and gave it a class I've made myself (hopefully that works).

Now, when I load the application, I want it to be able to load a webpage (my blog) into the scroll view

any idea how?

Regards,

Ryan

Comment: Not enough information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a UIWebView for loading web pages. The scroll for UIWebView would automatically adjust according to the size of the webpage.